# Proof that the orthonormal projection $P$ onto $W$ in a Hilbert space satisfies $P^2=P$ and $P*=P$.

Tags: hilbert-spaces, orthogonality, adjoint-operators, self-adjoint-operators

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space.

Given a closed subspace $W\subseteq H$, the orthogonal projection onto $W$ is the unique bounded linear operator $P$ such that $\text{Im}(P)=W$ and $\ker(P)=W^{\perp}$. The orthogonal projection $P$ satisfies:

1. $P^2=P$.
2. $P^*=P$, where $P^*$ is the adjoint of $P$.

---

I was wondering where I may find a proof of the above result, since there is no proof in my notes nor in the chapter on Hilbert spaces of Rudin's $\textit{Real and Complex Analysis}$.

Comment: Maybe there is some book that explicitly has this as a result, but in many others it could just be an exercise. To prove the existence, for each $x\in H$, prove that there is a unique $z=z_x\in W$ such that $\|x-z\|$ is minimum. Show that for this $z$ you have $z$ is orthogonal to $x-z$, Then define $P(x)=z$, The condition $P^2=P$ is clear from this definition. If $x,y\in H$, then $\langle Px,y\rangle=\langle Px,Py+(I-P)y\rangle=\langle Px,Py\rangle=\langle Px+(I-P)x,Py\rangle=\langle x,Py\rangle$, which shows that $P^*=P$.

Comment: One way to show uniqueness: Assume that $Q$ has the same properties. Let $x\in H$. The vector $Px-Qx\in W$ is orthogonal to all elements of $W^\bot$. Take any $y\in W$. Then, there is $z\in W$ such that $y=Qz$. Then $\langle y,Px-Qx\rangle=\langle Qz, Px-Qx\rangle=\langle z, Q(Px-x)\rangle=\langle Qz,Px -x\rangle=0$. Therefore $Px-Qx$ is orthogonal to all vectors, and therefore zero.

Comment: @user85667 in your uniqueness proof, you use the self-adjointness and idempotence. But the given definition implies that it is unique without those properties and that the properties follow purely from the description of the kernel and image (I believe that this is not the case and that the self-adjointness and idempotence should be baked in to the definition)

Comment: @hunter It is clear that, if they are looking for a reference, what they intend to find is the correct statement. To fix their wording one only needs to either remove a period or move the properties to an earlier position in their phrasing.

Answer (score 2):

I am confused -- it seems the given definition is not complete. If $H$ is $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the standard inner product and $W$ is the $x$-axis, then
$$
P = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
is a bounded linear operator such that $\text{Im}(P) = W$ and $\text{Ker}(P) = W^\perp$ even though it is not the orthogonal projection onto $W$ (and isn't idempotent).

Answer (score 0):

You need $P^{2}=P$ by definition for $P$ to be a projection.

> $\textbf{Definition:}$  Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space. A linear map $P: \mathcal{H}\rightarrow \mathcal{H}$ is called a projector if
> $$P^{2}=P\circ P = P$$
> and an orthogonal projector if in addition
> $$ran(P) \perp ker(P).$$

One can show that $$P\, orthogonal\, projection\; \text{if and only if}\; P=P^{\ast}.$$
For this we need

> $\textbf{Theorem:}$  Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space and W be a closed subspace of $\mathcal{H}$. Then there exists a unique orthogonal projector $P$ such that
> $$W=ran(P)\; \text{and}\;W^{\perp}=ker(P).$$
> Furthermore, for any $x\in\mathcal{H}$, there is a unique decomposition $$y=x_{1}+x_{2}\; \text{with}\;x_{1}\in W, x_{2} \in W^{\perp}$$
> with $x_{1}=Px$ and $x_{2}=(I-P)x$.

> For an operator T on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ it holds that $ker(T)=ran(T^{\ast})^{\perp}$ and $ker(T^{\ast})=ran(T)^{\perp}$.

$\mathbf{\Rightarrow}$
Let $x,y \in \mathcal{H}$. By the theorem above we can write $x=x_{W}+x_{W^{\perp}}$ and $y=y_{W}+y_{W^{\perp}}$ with $x_{W},y_{W}\in W$ and $x_{W^{\perp}},y_{W^{\perp}}\in W^{\perp}$.

It follows
$$
\begin{aligned}
\langle Tx,y \rangle
=&
\langle T(x_{W} +x_{W^{\perp}}),y_{W}+y_{W^{\perp}} \rangle\\
=&
\langle Tx_{W},y_{W} \rangle + \langle Tx_{W}, y_{W^{\perp}} \rangle + \langle Tx_{W^{\perp}},y_{W} \rangle + \langle Tx_{W^{\perp}}, y_{W^{\perp}} \rangle \\
=&
\langle Tx_{W},y_{W}\rangle\\
=&
\langle x_{W},y_{W}\rangle
\end{aligned}
$$ which follows since $Tx_{W}=x_{W}$,  $x_{W}  \perp y_{W^{\perp}}$ and $Tx_{W^{\perp}}=0$.
and
$$
\begin{aligned}
\langle x,Ty \rangle
=&
\left\langle x_{W} +x_{W^{\perp}},T(y_{W}+y_{W^{\perp}}) \right\rangle\\
=&
\langle x_{W},Ty_{W}\rangle + \langle x_{W},Ty_{W^{\perp}}\rangle + \langle x_{W^{\perp}},Ty_{W} \rangle + \langle x_{W^{\perp}},Ty_{W^{\perp}} \rangle\\
=&
\langle x_{W},y_{W}\rangle
\end{aligned}
$$ since $Ty_{W}=y_{W}$,  $x_{W}  \perp y_{W^{\perp}}$ and $Ty_{W^{\perp}}=0$.

Therefore $$\langle Tx ,y \rangle = \langle x,Ty \rangle\; \text{for all}\, x,y \in \mathcal{H}$$ thus $P$ is self-adjoint ($P=P^{\ast}).

$\mathbf{\Leftarrow}$
Let $P$ be self-adjoint ($P=P^{\ast}$). Together with  $ker(P)=ran(P^{\ast})^{\perp}$ this yields $ker(P)=ran(P)^{\perp}$ thus $P$ is an orthogonal projection.